# Rails 3 App: for oAuth-only sign-in using Facebook and Twitter, should I use Devise/OmniAuth, or just OmniAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, devise, twitter-oauth, omniauth

I'm creating a new Rails 3 app and I want to allow users to sign-in using their Facebook or Twitter credentials.

I don't know whether I should implement this using Devise and OmniAuth, or just OmniAuth. I just watched Ryan Bate's screencast on [Simple OmniAuth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth) and it seems like I could just use OmniAuth, but I'm not sure it's enough.

### I have the following requirements:

1. Allow sign-in via Facebook and/or Twitter. I will not be implementing local user accounts/passwords.
2. Signing in via FB/Twitter for the first time should create a new user in the db so I can store the associated FB/Twitter oAuth tokens.
3. Users should be able to associate both a FB and a Twitter acct to their profile/user so they can post to both FB and Twitter.
4. Users should be able to delete their account.

Comment: [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) alone should be sufficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted this on the Devise Google Mailing List and got this response from José Valim (Devise maintainer and Rails core team member):

> "You can use just OmniAuth. If you use Devise, the only benefit is that it will add Omniauth url helpers, but that is so minimal that honestly is not worth the overhead."
>   -- *José Valim*

Answer (score 1):

Devise is a fancy way to automatically handle all the things that go with user accounts.  If you don't need all the bells and whistles, you should definitely just go the Simple OmniAuth way like in the screencast.

The only hitch I see with trying to link up a Facebook and Twitter account is that you'll have to require them to be signed into one in order to link the other -- and if they do happen to sign in on separate occasions, you could possibly have two Users in your database. This wouldn't be a problem if you were doing Google and Facebook because they both send back an email address, but Twitter only sends back a username, no email address.

You'll have to add a field to the User model for a username (Twitter) and email address (Facebook) so you can attempt to link the accounts if a visitor did it separately and wants to link them later. Just be careful of that when you set it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use just OmniAuth, maybe because, like in my case, you want to use ActiveAdmin which depends on Devise and methods like `current_user` would conflict, you can just override the login page with your own:

```
match '/users/sign_in', :to => "sessions#new"
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

I have a "Sign in with Facebook" link in my nav, but this page is necessary for redirecting users when they're trying to access a protected page while not logged in.

**Edit**: Actually, there is a section on the [wiki page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview): *"Using OmniAuth without other authentications"*